# removing HTML tags and inseting space after tag?

Tags: javascript

```
<div><p><input type="radio" name="choice"><span>text1</span></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="choice"><span>text2</span></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="choice"><span>text3</span></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="choice"><span>text4</span></p>

</div>
```

i want to remove the html tags , also i need to get all the data in new line, i can get the data using following code, but how i insert line between them ?

code for getting text without tags in a single line ?

```
function getInfo(Description) {
  return Description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
}
```

i want output like

```
text1
text2
text3
```

Comment: some code is there that is not displaying

Comment: i want the text by removing the tags in line by line

Comment: @kiran Where is the HTML coming from?

Comment: from the javascript page itself ? in case of editing i want to pick that data and display that .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XgUrG/2/.. how can i get this in line by line each text should be in seperate line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kiran: Perhaps something like --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getInfo(Description) {
        var tmp = Description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        return tmp.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
    }
    var somevar;
    somevar  = "<div><p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice\"><span>text1</span></p>\n";
    somevar += "<p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice\"><span>text2</span></p>\n";
    somevar += "<p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice\"><span>text3</span></p>\n";
    somevar += "<p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice\"><span>text4</span></p>\n";

    document.write(getInfo(somevar));
</script>
```

Comment: @stealthyninja , its not workint , coming in the same line only

Comment: @kiran: If your source data doesn't contain newlines, then the second replacement line won't work...

Comment: function getInfo(Description) {
alert(Description);//   <p><input name="choice" type="radio"><span>text1</span></p><p><input name="choice" type="radio"><span>text2</span></p><p><input name="choice" type="radio"><span>text3</span></p>
        var tmp = Description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        return tmp.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
    }

Comment: @stealthyninja : this is my innerHTML returned data , it gives data in single line only  <div id="container">
<p >
    <input name="choice"  type="radio"><span>text1</span></p><p><input  name="choice"  type="radio"><span>text2</span></p><p><input  name="choice" type="radio"><span>text3</span></p></div>

Comment: @stealthninja : can u help me in this ?

Comment: @stealthninja , help me in this

Comment: @stealthyninja, im getting like this    text1<br>text2<br>text3...y?

Comment: @stealthyninja, thank u, it worked beautifully, i replace that <br> with '/n' , thank u